# To get ID of Textbox dynamically and assign to a variable

Tags: asp.net

I have a Grid Under the  ContentPlaceholder here the grid is Dynamic where it rows will be increasing accordingly to the Values i pass from Database.
On pageload if my Grid contains 5rows for example, i want to get the ID of all the Textbox which is in Grid Dynamically and assign it to the Variable.
How to do it..

When i Run the page and checked view source from browser i got my Textbox name like this

```
"ctl00_MainContent_gvtemp_ctl00_ctl04_txtDescription"
"ctl00_MainContent_gvtemp_ctl00_ctl06_txtDescription"
"ctl00_MainContent_gvtemp_ctl00_ctl08_txtDescription"
"ctl00_MainContent_gvtemp_ctl00_ctl10_txtDescription"
"ctl00_MainContent_gvtemp_ctl00_ctl12_txtDescription"
```

I need to Pass those Id to Var ids like below..

```
var ids = ["ctl00_MainContent_gvtemp_ctl00_ctl04_txtDescription",
                "ctl00_MainContent_gvtemp_ctl00_ctl06_txtDescription",
                "ctl00_MainContent_gvtemp_ctl00_ctl08_txtDescription",
                 "ctl00_MainContent_gvtemp_ctl00_ctl10_txtDescription",
                 "ctl00_MainContent_gvtemp_ctl00_ctl12_txtDescription",
                  "ctl00_MainContent_gvtemp_ctl00_ctl14_txtDescription",
                  "ctl00_MainContent_gvtemp_ctl00_ctl16_txtDescription"];
```

Here my Grid Coding:

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="gvtemp" AllowSorting="false" AllowPaging="false" runat="server"
                                                    CssClass="grid tBorder" ShowFooter="false" AllowMultiRowSelection="false" AllowMultiRowEdit="false"
                                                    AllowFilteringByColumn="false" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                                    AlternatingItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                    <MasterTableView>
                                                        <Columns>
                                                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Brand" ItemStyle-Width="3%">
                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblBrand" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BRAND") %>' />
                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="50%" UniqueName="Description">
                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DESCRIPTION") %>'
                                                                        Height="75px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%"/>
                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                                        </Columns>
                                                        <EditFormSettings>
                                                            <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
                                                            </EditColumn>
                                                        </EditFormSettings>
                                                    </MasterTableView>
                                                   <HeaderContextMenu CssClass="GridContextMenu GridContextMenu_">
                                                    </HeaderContextMenu>
                                                </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? No one has time to implement complete functionality. and paste your markup for gridview tto

Comment: I have tried like following 
var masterTable = $find("<%= gvtemp.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                var row = masterTable.get_dataItems();
                for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                    var txtid = masterTable.get_dataItems()[i].findElement("txtDescription");
                    var ids = [txtid];
                    
                }

Comment: first thing, it's jQuery and you mentioned javascript in your question and don't be lazy and pase your code in question

Comment: var txt = document.getElementById('<%=txtDescription.ClientID%>');
            var ids = [txt];

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
var objs = $('[id$=txtDescription]');
var ids = []; 
objs.each(function()
{
    ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

[**Check fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cbw7m2cw/)

Answer (score 0):

1.I tried and got the ID of the textbox like below

```
    var masterTable = $find("<%= gvtemp.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
    var row = masterTable.get_dataItems();
    var ids = new Array(row);
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    var rowid = masterTable.get_dataItems([i].findElement("txtDescription").id;
    ids[i] = rowid;
    }
```